# Show label based on zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Depending on the zoomlevel I want to show or hide the label of a marker, I've had a look on here for the answers and while I've got a better idea of what I'm meant to be doing I haven't had any luck being able to implement it into my google map. the label should only show when zoom level is >7.

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      center: {lat: 52.024, lng: 2.887}        
    });

    setMarkers(map);
  }

     var tasks = [
['Marker 1', 32.89, 12.25, 78],
['Marker 2', 60.29, -4.29, 83],
['Marker 3', 57.39, 1.5, 85],
['Marker 4', 52.50, 4, 94]
  ];

  function setMarkers(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      var task = tasks[i];
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat: task[1], lng: task[2]},
        map: map,
        title: task[0],
        label: task[0],
        url: "somesite?ID=" + task[3]
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
      window.location.href = this.url;
    });

  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save references to your markers in an array.  Create a 'zoom_changed' listener on the map, when it executes, process through the array of markers hiding the label (set it to null) if zoom is <= 7, displaying the label (setting it equal to title) if the zoom is > 7.

```
  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    for (var i=0; i< gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (map.getZoom() > 7) {
        gmarkers[i].setLabel(gmarkers[i].getTitle());
      } else {
        gmarkers[i].setLabel(null);
      }
    }
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ao5mktf8/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 52.024,
      lng: 2.887
    }
  });

  setMarkers(map);
  map.addListener('zoom_changed', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
      if (map.getZoom() > 7) {
        gmarkers[i].setLabel(gmarkers[i].getTitle());
      } else {
        gmarkers[i].setLabel(null);
      }
    }
  });
}

var tasks = [
  ['Marker 1', 32.89, 12.25, 78],
  ['Marker 2', 60.29, -4.29, 83],
  ['Marker 3', 57.39, 1.5, 85],
  ['Marker 4', 52.50, 4, 94]
];
var gmarkers = [];

function setMarkers(map) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
    var task = tasks[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: task[1],
        lng: task[2]
      },
      map: map,
      title: task[0],
      url: "somesite?ID=" + task[3]
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      window.location.href = this.url;
    });

  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been very close to this... Just couldn’t tie it together. I was looking for any setlabel mentions in the reference but couldn’t find it

Comment: [Marker.setLabel](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/marker#Marker.setLabel)